# Equivalent regex without negative lookahead

Tags: regex, go, traefik, traefik-middleware

I am trying to setup a [Traefik RedirextRegex](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/redirectregex/) middleware. But since that uses Golang's STD re lib, it does not support negative lookaheads (`?!`).

All but the following URLs must be redirected:

```
https://example.com/whatever/else
https://example.com/application/o/authorize/
https://example.com/application/o/authorize/Rand0m
https://example.com/application/o/authorize/Rand0m?abc=123
https://example.com/application/o/RaNd0m/end-session/
https://example.com/application/o/RaNd0m/end-session/Rand0m
https://example.com/application/o/RaNd0m/end-session/Rand0m?abc=123
```

I've come up with this regex:

```
^https?://[^/]+/application/o/(?!authorize|.*/end-session).*$
```

But because negative lookahead is not supported, I cannot use it.

For completeness, here are some expected URLs that must be redirected:

```
https://example.com/application/o/RaNd0m/
https://example.com/application/o/RaNd0m/Rand0m
https://example.com/application/o/token/
https://example.com/application/o/token/Rand0m
https://example.com/application/o/userinfo/
https://example.com/application/o/userinfo/Rand0m
https://example.com/application/o/introspect/
https://example.com/application/o/introspect/Rand0m
https://example.com/application/o/revoke/
https://example.com/application/o/revoke/Rand0m
https://example.com/application/o/device/
https://example.com/application/o/device/Rand0m
https://example.com/application/o/RaNd0m/jwks/
https://example.com/application/o/RaNd0m/jwks/Rand0m
```

Is it possible to keep the same meaning but use only features supported by Golang's re lib?

Comment: Look for valid routes and if not valid then redirect. Why did you choose the "hard" way?

Comment: @Akxe  How would that look like as a K8s ingress path rule?

Comment: I decided to see what it would take to match anything except `abcd` using patterns of matching and not matching each letter.  The regex for just 4 letters, is very large: [`^(?:.{1,3}|.{5,}|[^a][^b][^c][^d]|[a][^b][^c][^d]|[^a][b][^c][^d]|[^a][^b][c][^d]|[^a][^b][^c][d]|[a][b][^c][^d]|[a][^b][c][^d]|[a][^b][^c][d]|[^a][b][c][^d]|[^a][b][^c][d]|[^a][^b][c][d]|[^a][b][c][d]|[a][^b][c][d]|[a][b][^c][d]|[a][b][c][^d])$`](https://regex101.com/r/8QLHH3/1)

Comment: @Darin It need not be that long. [`^(?:.{1,3}|.{5,}|[^a].{3}|.[^b].{2}|.{2}[^c].|.{3}[^d])$`](https://regex101.com/r/8QLHH3/2) will do.

Comment: @InSync, thank you.  I did that at the end of a long day and clearly I wasn't thinking - clearly.  If I'm not mistaken, your answer, with a little work, could be an answer for Slav.

Comment: You can go 2 different ways. On a logic line, Match the bad ones first -> `^https?://[^/]+/application/o/(?:(?:authorize|.*/end-session)).*$`
https://regex101.com/r/WKlQxw/1 If that matches skip redirection. If not, run a regex without the exclusions. If that is fine, redirect that one. Second option, run a regex that handles both. This one captures the bad part. This will be a flag not to redirect. -> `^https?://[^/]+/application/o/(?:(authorize|.*/end-session))?.*$`
https://regex101.com/r/pgakzo/1

Comment: In general, there is no workaround for lack of assertions, no matter what your brain tells you.

Comment: What @Darin and @InSync suggest is long but might work.  I need to test. @sln , unfortunately there is no way to tell the middleware to redirect when the regex does NOT match.  However, maybe I can set up 2 redirect regex middlewares - one to match the `authorize`, `end-session`, and `/whatever/else` URLs, and redirect to whatever was matched (i.e. not changing anything) and another middleware after it that redirects everything (.*) to a different URL. Although I suspect both middlewares will end up being applied to every request instead of just the first that matches. Needs testing.